# Selenium RC Timeout

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, phpunit, selenium-rc

I am new to test unit stuff. My configuration is a windows vista combined with phpunit and selenium rc (selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar).

I have tried loading a testcase file on my prompt command: 
one prompt command launches selenium server:

```
@echo
rem comment
cd c:\progra~1\java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -interactive
```

It loads, no problem, I launch on another prompt command phpunit, and make:

```
phpunit testcase.php
```

It works too, but I get this:

an C:\wamp\www\projet>phpunit testcase.php
PHPUnit 3.7.19 by Sebastian Bergmann.

E

Time: 47 seconds, Memory: 2.50Mb

There was 1 error:

1) Example::testMyTestCase

```
Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http://localhost:4444/s
elenium-server/driver/': Timed out after 30000ms

C:\wamp\www\projet\testcase.php:18
C:\wamp\www\projet\testcase.php:18

Caused by
RuntimeException: Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http:
//localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/': Timed out after 30000ms

C:\wamp\www\projet\testcase.php:18
C:\wamp\www\projet\testcase.php:18
```

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

Here is the testcase.php file:

```php
<?php

require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php';

class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
  function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("*firefox");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://www.google.com/");
  }

  function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->open("http://www.google.com/");
    $this->type("q", "selenium rc");
    $this->click("btnG");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    $this->assertTrue($this->isTextPresent("Results * for selenium rc"));
  }
}
?>
```

Where is the fail? Thanks.
nicenicer.